# Setting directory in Linux

Tags: linux

Someone please advise how to set the directory to chown root:root and chmod 0600, so that everything in it was created or copy the same settings as configured directory? thank you

Comment: You want to set the directory to be owned by the group and user root, as well as all files within that directory recursively? Is that what you are asking? If so, adding the -R switch to chmod and chown makes them both recursive.

Comment: // , Please rephrase this as a question, show what you've tried already, and what you've researched already.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear ... but I think that perhaps what you're looking for is *recursive* application to apply `chown` and `chmod` settings to all files in the directory.  This can be done (in both cases) using the `-R` flag, for example:

```
chown -R root:root mydir/*
```

Comment: No, i do recursive settings... example: chown root:root /tmp/foo and chmod 0600 /tmp/foo. Now create a directory or file, I want to set root: root 0600, automatically or copy directory and file to /tmp/foo. Thank

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `chmod -R 0600 *` and `chown -R root:root *`, but your question is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the -R (recursive) flag - you can use 
`chown -R root:root /your/directory/full/path` 
and 
`chmod -R 0600 /your/directory/full/path`

If instead you're copying an existing directory and want to retain permissions you can use 
`cp -a /current/path /new/path` 
and the -a flag will keep ownership and permissions the same

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question now: you're trying to set the *default* permissions and ownership for new files in the directory.

For **ownership**, if you add yourself to the group that owns the directory (`root` in this case), then new files you create will be owned by that group.

For **permissions**, you can set default permissions for new files using [umask](http://linuxzoo.net/page/sec_umask.html):

```
umask 077  # grant only user r/w permissions
```

or using `setfacl`: see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/how-to-set-default-file-permissions-for-all-folders-files-in-a-directory) for more information.